# How to use a subquery as a function paramter?

Tags: sql, hive

If I want to create a "user variable" in a SQL script I usually create a parameters WITH statement at the top, to give the script user a single place to change the variable before running the script.  Like this:

```
WITH  parms AS (
          select '2022-01-01' AS data_date
)

SELECT  SUM(a.amount) AS total
FROM    a
JOIN    parms
  ON    1=1
WHERE   a.data_date BETWEEN 
                       DATE_FORMAT(parms.data_date,'yyyy-MM-01') --BOM
                       AND
                       LAST_DAY(parms.data_date) --EOM

UNION ALL
{table b}
...
{table x}
UNION ALL

SELECT  SUM(z.amount) AS total
FROM    z
JOIN    parms
  ON    1=1
WHERE   z.data_date BETWEEN 
                       DATE_FORMAT(parms.data_date,'yyyy-MM-01') --BOM
                       AND
                       LAST_DAY(parms.data_date) --EOM
;
```

My problem is my tables `a` through `z` each contain hundreds of millions of rows and I think joining `parms on 1=1` for every row must be expensive.

I'd like to eliminate `join parms` on every row and instead select parms in the `WHERE`:

```
WHERE   a.data_date BETWEEN 
                       DATE_FORMAT((select parms.data_date from parms limit 1),'yyyy-MM-01') --BOM
                       AND
                       LAST_DAY(select parms.data_date from parms limit 1) --EOM
```

Is using a subquery in a function parameter possible? Am I on the right approach to speed this up?

If I must, I can fall back to eliminating `WITH parms` and instead sprinkle the date throughout the script in each `WHERE` statement.

EDIT: Forgot to add I am limited to a single SQL statement.  I cannot declare variables in a separate statement.

Comment: Re " joining `parms on 1=1` for every row must be expensive" - I don't know nothing about particular SQL optimizer, but it could be possible that it is able to remove join entirely and use constant directly. You can't assume that join order and conditions are executed "literally".

Comment: @Arvo I know, that is true but in my mind it would have to join the date on every row before it can evaluate the same date field in `WHERE`.  I could be totally wrong, and this effort could be in vain.  But I still want to try as a learning exercise for myself, and hopefully to speed up the query.

Comment: I would try and compare query plans and execution times. You could calculate your BOM and EOM values inside CTE as dates (this may be important!) and join your queries by `join parms on a.data_date between parms.BOM and parms.EOM` - or join result of unioned query in simlar way, whichever looks nicer. Inner join by expression or where condition by same expression should result in similar execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable and refer to that in the where clause.

```
DECLARE @data_date VARCHAR(8) = '22-01-01';

SELECT  SUM(a.amount) AS total
FROM    a
WHERE   a.data_date BETWEEN 
                       DATE_FORMAT(@data_date,'yyyy-MM-01') --BOM
                       AND
                       LAST_DAY(@data_date) --EOM
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot to mention that I have to do this in a single statement.  Is it possible to declare a var in the same statement as the `SELECT`?